# localStorage is null, but only from one function and not another

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a PHP page that loads two JS files at the end. In the first file I have this...

```
// global variables
var refineSearchStorage = {};

// function calls
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  refineSearchStorage.get();
});

refineSearchStorage = {
  data : null, // empty storage
  get : function() {
    refineSearchStorage.data = localStorage.getItem("refineSearchStorage");
    if(refineSearchStorage.data === null) { 
      refineSearchStorage.data = { refineKeywords: '' };
      refineSearchStorage.save();
    }
    else { 
      refineSearchStorage.data = JSON.parse(refineSearchStorage.data); 
    }
  },
  add : function(x) {
    refineSearchStorage.data.refineKeywords = x;
    refineSearchStorage.save();
  },
  save : function() {
    localStorage.setItem("refineSearchStorage", JSON.stringify(refineSearchStorage.data));
  }
};
```

Inline javascript calls Function 1 from the middle of the page. It is created by PHP after a search result...

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    searchActions('{$keywords_human}');
  });
</script>
```

Function 1 appears in the 2nd JS page and the result is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'refineKeywords' of null`... instead of adding to the localStorage.

```
function searchActions(x) {
  refineSearchStorage.add(x);
}
```

Function 2 below is called with the click of a button and adds to a localStorage variable without issue. It is also located on the 2nd JS page...

```
function keywordAdd(y) {
  var existingParams = refineSearchStorage.data.refineKeywords;
  var param = y.toLowerCase();
  var newParams;
  newParams = (existingParams + ' ' + param).trim();
  refineSearchStorage.add(newParams);
}
```

Function 1 used to work, but I did something to break it when I split the functions on to different pages. What did I do?

Comment: Can you check the value of `refineSearchStorage.data` after this line `refineSearchStorage.data = JSON.parse(refineSearchStorage.data)` its seem the value from json.parse is null ( or it throw an error )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    searchActions('{$keywords_human}');
  });
```

gets called before

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  refineSearchStorage.get();
});
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. I was searching the code for several hours, and at 4 AM I was too tired to think properly. I moved calling `searchActions()` to the end of the page under the javascript file calls, checking for `isset($_POST['search'])` so it only shows after a search, and now everything is working again. I just wish I could remember how my code was ordered before the split. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your **data** attribute is **null**

[(screenshot) See what I mean by that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53puX.png)

convert add to

```js
add : function(x) {
    refineSearchStorage.data = refineSearchStorage.data || {};  // this might help
    refineSearchStorage.data.refineKeywords = x;
    refineSearchStorage.save();
},
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Alex's answer pointed to the source of the problem.

Comment: sure no problem